# Asking my code to extract data from database, stop until data is extracted and then continue executing the macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that updates all data connections on my workbook, waits until they update and then continues executing the rest of my macro. This code works without any issues.

```
Sub Refresh_All_Data_Connections()

    For Each objConnection In ThisWorkbook.Connections
        'Get current background-refresh value
        bBackground = objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery
        
        'Temporarily disable background-refresh
        objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
        
        'Refresh this connection
        objConnection.Refresh
        
        'Set background-refresh value back to original value
        objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = bBackground
    Next
    
    Call copy_paste_data
    
End Sub
```

Now, what I'm trying to do, is basically the same thing but instead of refreshing all data connections, just update an specific table.

So all I do is change the following line of code

```
objConnection.Refresh
```

for this one

```
 Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Refresh
```

But this doesn't work, the code starts refreshing the data connection, but it doesn't wait until it finishes refreshing, so it continues running my macro, which is not what I want it to do.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - <query name>").Refresh`.  You might have to disable background refresh, or use a `DoEvents`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I thought I had already disabled background refresh with objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook How could I find the name of the connection if I wanted to use this? ThisWorkbook.Connections("    ").Refresh

Comment: It should be the name of your power query with "Query -" stuck on the front.  That's assuming the connections are from power query?

Comment: Have you tried `Worksheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("Table1").QueryTable.BackgroundQuery = False` and `Worksheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("Table1").QueryTable.Refresh`?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook This worked, if you submit it as an answer I can select it as the solution for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to the query behind the table using

`Worksheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("Table1").QueryTable`.

Using a `With...End With` this could be written as

```
Sub T()

    With Worksheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("Table1").QueryTable
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .Refresh
        .BackgroundQuery = True
    End With

End Sub
```